# gnuplot stock chart using date on x axis

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to use gnuplot for the first time. 
I am completely new to gnuplot. Please forgive any basic mistakes.
I am trying to plot a stock chart.
My data looks like the following:

```
Date Open High Low Close
21/04/2017 31.81 32.09 31.67 31.95
20/04/2017 31.55 32.02 31.45 31.91
19/04/2017 31.3 31.71 30.99 31.57
18/04/2017 31.78 31.84 31.06 31.3
17/04/2017 31.3 31.97 31.21 31.8
13/04/2017 31.26 31.48 31.16 31.19
12/04/2017 31.13 31.38 30.98 31.24
11/04/2017 31.37 31.66 30.86 31.2
```

I am using the following settings to plot the lines. I got them from another website.

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d/%m/%Y"
set xrange ["21/04/2015":"21/04/2017"]
set format x "%d/%m/%Y"
plot [0:100] 'chart.dat' using 0:2:3:4:5 notitle with financebars
```

However, the x-axis just has 01/01/1970. See attached pic. [image: chart.png]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The plot command `plot [0:100] ... using 0:2:3:4:5` takes column 0 for x, column 0 corresponds to the line number instead of the time column.

This command should work:

```
plot 'chart.dat' using 1:2:3:4:5 notitle with financebars
```

Comment: I tried that before. This is what I get. "gnuplot> plot [0:100] 'chart.dat' using 1:2:3:4:5 notitle with financebars
                                                                              ^
         all points y value undefined!"

Comment: The `[0:100]` specifies the x range (again) and sets it to 0 ... 100 seconds starting from 1970 in your case. There is no data in this range. You have an explicit `set xrange`, so you can skip the `[0:100]` in the plot command.

Comment: Hi Maij. If I use this "plot chart.dat' using 0:2:3:4:5 notitle with financebars", then all I get is 01/01/1970 on the x-axis. If I simpify it to just "plot 'chart.dat' using 1:4 notitle with lines", then I get the correct dates in the x-axis. So, to reference the date colum, I need to specify column 1. Looking at all the references to financebars and candlesticks, they all use the syntax 0:2:3:4:5. Which still leaves me scratching my head on how to use column 1 as the date colum with financebars or candlesticks. I tried, 1:0:2:3:4:5 and that didn't work either. Cheers.

Comment: What do you get if you just copy `plot 'chart.dat' using 1:2:3:4:5 notitle with financebars`?

Comment: Awesome! That finally did the trick! Thanks very much, Maij. It works now. Cheers.